# Unexpected use of comma operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have following error message:

> Unexpected use of comma operator     no-sequences

This is the code:

```
<Icon.Clipboard onClick={() => (

    this.handleModal("open","modify"), this.prettyPrint(JSON.stringify(res)))}
/>
```

Where does the problem come from?

Comment: I would say it comes from your comma `,` ... Why do you have this there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `,` after `this.handleModal("open","modify")`. That arrow function should use a full function body (`{` after the `=>` and its accompanying `}` at the end) and a statement separator (`;` or newline) between the two function calls:

```
<Icon.Clipboard onClick={() => {
    this.handleModal("open","modify");
    return this.prettyPrint(JSON.stringify(res));
}} />
```

Or more likely, you don't want that `return` (but that's what your code using the comma operator was doing):

```
<Icon.Clipboard onClick={() => {
    this.handleModal("open","modify");
    this.prettyPrint(JSON.stringify(res));
}} />
```

The comma operator evaluates its left-hand operand, then throws that result away, evalutes its right-hand operand, and takes that as its result. It's commonly abused as a statement separator, but it isn't one and doing so can have unintended consequences (such as returning the result of `printPrint` above — probably harmless in this case, but often not).